# How to seperate Vue logic in a laravel app based on layout and page templates

Tags: forms, laravel, vue.js, structure, laravel-blade

I have a laravel app and a Vue instance attached to the body (or a div, just inside the body).

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

I think it makes sense to use the Vue instance for stuff relating to the layout (eg header, nav, footer logic).

Now I have a form that is visible on a specific route (e.g. `example.com/thing/create`). I want to add some logic to it, e.g. hiding a field based on selected option in the form. It is logic meant for just this form (not to be reused). I prefer not to put all the logic inline with the form but put it in the app.js. I could put it in the Vue instance bound to the body but that sounds odd as it only applies to the form that is much deeper into the dom.

I want to leave the markup of the form in the blade template (that inherits the layout).

I tried creating a component but am not sure how to bind this inside the main Vue instance. What is the best way to handle things for this form, put it in the app.js and have it somewhat structured, putting the variables somewhat into scope. Or is it really necessary to remove the main Vue instance bound to the full layout code?

What I tried was something like this, but it does not work (attaching it to the `<form id="object-form">` seems to fail:

```
var ObjectForm = {
    template: function() { return '#object-form'},
    data: function() {
        return {
            selectedOption: 1
        }
    },
    computed: {
        displayField: function() {
            // return true or false depending on form state
            return true;
        }
    }
};
```

Things do work if I remove the #app Vue instance or when I put everything directly in the app Vue instance. But that seems messy, if I have similar variables for another form they should be seperated somewhat. 
I would appreciate some advice regarding the structure (differentiate page layout and page specific forms) and if possible some example to put the form logic inside the main app.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do it. The trick was to use an inline template. Surround the form in the view with:

```
<object-form inline-template>
    <form>...</form>
</object-form>
```

Where object-form is the name of the component. In the ObjectForm code above I remove the template, like this:

```
var ObjectForm = {
    data: function() {
        return {
            selectedOption: 1
        }
    },
    computed: {
        displayField: function() {
            // return true or false depending on form state
            return true;
        }
    }
};
```

I attach the component within the root vue app like this:

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: 'body',
    components: {
        'object-form': ObjectForm
    }
});
```

This way I can use the form as it was generated from the controller and view and I can separate it from the root (attached to body) methods and properties.

To organize it even better I can probably store the ObjectForm in a seperate .vue file the way @Tayler Foster suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps kind of break things down for you and helps you understand Vue templating.

It is best to take advantage of Vue's components. For you it would look something like this. Some of this code depends on your file structure, but you should be able to understand it.

In your `app.js` file (or your main js file)

```
Vue.component('myform',require('./components/MyForm.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app"
});
```

Then create the `MyForm.vue file`

```
<template>
 <form> 
  Put Your Form Markup Here
 </form>
</template>

<script>
 // Here is where you would handle the form scripts.
 // Use methods, props, data to help set up your component
  module.exports = {
    data: function() {
        return {
            selectedOption: 1
        }
    },
    computed: {
        displayField: function() {
            // return true or false depending on form state
            return true;
        }
    },
   methods: {
     // add methods for dynamically changing form values
   }
  }
</script>
```

Then you will be able to just call in your blade file.

```
<myform></myform>
```

Comment: I used components for other sites, however the markup and php is in the blade template page and would prefer to leave it there as is and not take it out of the page and put it into the component. It doesn't have to be reusable but the methods and variables should be somewhat in their own scope. It would be nice if I can attach the component to the form id. It would be difficult to add my php code for the subview to my Vue file I suppose.